# i was working on a code i.e spliting the pdf using keywords such that each pdf should start with keyword and ends with empty page

Tags: python, nlp, google-colaboratory

import os
import re
import fitz  # PyMuPDF
import spacy

## Load a spaCy language model (you can choose a different one if needed)

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

## Define your PDF file name and keywords

pdf_file = '/content/sample.pdf'  # Replace with the path to your PDF file in Colab
output_folder = '/content/output'  # Replace with your desired output folder path
keywords = ['Rakesh', 'Shephali', 'Supriya']

## Create the output folder if it doesn't exist

os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)

## Function to split the PDF with each resulting PDF starting with the respective keyword

def split_pdf(pdf_file, output_folder):
pdf_document = fitz.open(pdf_file)

```
for keyword in keywords:
    pdf_writer = fitz.open()
    
    for page_num in range(pdf_document.page_count):
        page = pdf_document.load_page(page_num)
        text = page.get_text()
        
        # Use spaCy for keyword matching
        doc = nlp(text)
        keyword_found = False
        
        for token in doc:
            if re.search(keyword, token.text, re.IGNORECASE):
                keyword_found = True
                break
        
        if keyword_found:
            # Start a new PDF with the keyword page
            pdf_writer.insert_pdf(page)
            
            # Add an empty page after the keyword page
            empty_page = fitz.open()
            empty_page.new_page()
            pdf_writer.insert_pdf(empty_page)
    
    # Save the new PDF with the keyword in the file name
    output_pdf = os.path.join(output_folder, f'{keyword}_pages.pdf')
    pdf_writer.save(output_pdf)
```

## Check if this script is being run as the main program

if **name** == '**main**':
split_pdf(pdf_file, output_folder)

im getting the error of:  AttributeError: 'Page' object has no attribute '_graft_id'

please me to get rid from this.

I'm expecting the error-free solution which will run in Jupiter as well as in colab.